# Registering a javascript method in GWT java code so that it can be invoked based on an event in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, callback

I tried looking for a similar post but couldn't find any, hence posting this query for your help. Essentially, I have a custom UI created on the GWT side. Now, I want to send events occuring at the GWT side over to the javascript/jsp page. For this I was wondering if there's a way for the jsp/javascript to register a method in the GWT code, and whenever, any event happens at the GWT side, the GWT java code can simply invoke this javascript method (which is like a function pointer/object), and the information would be notified at the jsp page. Though  I can directly call javascript methods from within the GWT code, however, that means that the GWT code also need to know the javascript method name, and this results in a tight coupling. Instead the javascript could simply pass in a handle to the function to the GWT code, which would simply invoke this handle to pass in necessary events on the jsp/javascript code. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Dictionary`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) to pass the function name to your application.

In the JSP host page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    // Do stuff...
  }

  var MyDictionary = {
    myCallback = "myFunction"
  };
</script>
```

And in your application:

```
public void onEvent(EventType event) {
  Dictionary d = Dictionary.getDictionary("MyDictionary");
  invokeNativeCallback(d.get("myCallback"));
}

private native void invokeNativeCallback(String callbackName) /*-{
  if (typeof $wnd[callbackName] === "function") {
    $wnd[callbackName]();
  }
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jason. This looks like the approach I was looking for, but I was wondering is there a way to pass in the Dictionary object to the GWT code? I mean for registering the myDictionary variable, like you've mentioned in the jsp page, we'd need to register this through another JSNI method exposed on the GWT side. I'm aware that we can pass in primitive data types from javascript to GWT, but for passing in a Dictionary object, is there a special notation for it? Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: `Dictionary` is a bridge from GWT to a global JavaScript object containing String values. You don't need a JSNI method to get the dictionary, just the name of the variable. There is no way to pass a parameter directly via your top level `onModuleLoad()`.

Comment: Oh,so you're mentioning that I can directly access the global myDictionary variable from within the GWT code in any native method, and then use it subsequently like the way you've mentioned above, or the code you've mentioned above can be used directly as it without any modifications? Once again, many thanks for your help here.